# Display tooltip with diferent values for each bar using recharts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I have a chart and I want to display a tooltip for each bar with its data.

I used this example from their documentation https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/CustomContentOfTooltip

I created a custom tooltip element

```
   const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload }: TooltipProps<number, string>) =>{
        console.log(payload)
        if (active) {
          return (
            <div className="custom-tooltip">
                {payload && payload[0]  &&
                    <p className="label">{`${payload![0].name}: ${payload![0].value}`}</p>
                }
            </div>
          );
        }
        return null;
      };
```

and this is bar chart element where I use the custom tooltip as in the example above.

```
<BarChart> 
 ...
 <Tooltip cursor={false} content={<CustomTooltip />} />
{Object.values(dataKeyBar).map(({chart, color}, index) => {
   return <Bar
         radius={barSize}
         key={`bar-${index}`}
         barSize={barSize}
         dataKey={chart}
         fill={color}
     />
  })}
</BarChart>
```

My problem is no matter what bar I'm hovering, I get the same data in my tooltip -

```
{`${payload![0].name}: ${payload![0].value}`}
```

[image]

the payload looks like this:

[image]

what I have tried to display different data in the tooltip for each bar is for the customTooltip but the tooltip is not showing at all.

```
 {payload && payload.map((bar: any) => {
      return  <div className="custom-tooltip"><p className="label">{`${bar.name}: ${bar.value}`}</p></div>
    })}
```

How can I display a tooltip with different data for each bar?

Comment: here can u pls create an example so I can help u.